# When to declare Class Extension Methods

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've made use of Class Extensions in the .m as a way to have "private" methods and variables. I've read that since Xcode 4.4, the compiler no longer needed the private methods declared.

For example this would compile even though helperMethodC is not declared:

in .h

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
-(void)publicMethodA;
@end
```

in .m

```
@interface MyClass ()
- (void) pseudoPrivateMethodB;
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)publicMethodA
{ 
   //Do Something
}

- (void)pseudoPrivateMethodB 
{   
 [self helperMethodC];
}

- (void) helperMethodC
{
 // Do something
}
```

While private methods no longer have to be declared to compile (helperMethodC), is there a style guide, historical reason, or rule that all private methods (i.e. helperMethodC) should still be declared? Or a "rule" for when to declare and not declare private methods?

Comment: FYI - They were never required unless you had a circular dependency. You could otherwise avoid them by putting your methods in an order that precluded the need to have the private declarations. In other words, the code you posted would always compile if you put `helperMethodC` before `pseudoPrivateMethodB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare them if they help you. From a documentation point of view they are very useful. The compiler will also tell you if you have specified that a method will exist and then not implemented it. There is no rule, but its a good idea to add them. Consider how you'll feel if you have to come back in 6 months and edit the class - will having the methods listed there help you?

Comment: Another point to throw into the balance is that keeping the method declarations is a kind of duplication. If you change a method signature you have to edit it twice, or the compiler will annoy you with a warning.

Comment: Also, you'll need an extension if you want to declare an @property to be publicly readonly and privately readwrite.   Extensions are also useful when broken out into a separate file to share some private-to-several-classes API.

Answer (score 0):

> While private methods no longer have to be declared to compile (helperMethodC), is there a style guide, historical reason, or rule that all private methods (i.e. helperMethodC) should still be declared? Or a "rule" for when to declare and not declare private methods?

There are multiple conventions, but no standard.

You *really* should have them when/if you need to support older toolchains -- GCC or older versions of Clang.

Once that restriction is removed, I think it's best if you just phase the (redundant) declarations out where they are not needed. High warning levels and ARC semantics can guide you here.

If you introduce types:

```
Something * s = [array objectAtIndex:i];
s.string = @"string";
// rather than: [array objectAtIndex:i].string = @"string";
```

And name your selectors uniquely for the parameter/return types:

```
// BAD: May be ambiguous.
// Solution: Choose a more descriptive selector name.

// class A
- (void)setX:(int)x;

// class B
- (void)setX:(double)x;
```

then the compiler can inform you of ambiguities.